# How to setup multiple ipv6 addresses with dyndns in xubuntu?

Tags: ipv6, dyndns

How to add extra 5 ipv6 addresses to my xubuntu and register them with dyndns?

My xubuntu 14.10 have automatically configured ipv4 and ipv6 addresses:

```
sam@minisrv1:~$ ip -6 addr show eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 2001:470:**:***:94ef:b2f6:70bb:1674/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 600084sec preferred_lft 81084sec
    inet6 2001:470:**:***:222:4dff:fea1:389f/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic
       valid_lft 4294096507sec preferred_lft 4294096507sec
    inet6 fe80::222:4dff:fea1:389f/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Perfect!!!

Now I want to add extra 5 ipv6 addresses and make them registered wiht dyndns.
What is RIGHT way to do it?

I checked `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` config files, but them say nothing about eth0:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

and

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

The folder `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` is empty too.

Also I tryied GUI tools "Network Connections" and "Editing Wired Connection 1". But i don't know what to write to `Prefix`, `Gateway` and other fields. They all comes from router.

And finally, I have no idea where to put my dyndns update scripts

```
curl "http://dyn.dns.he.net/nic/update?hostname=***&password=***&myip=???" > /dev/null
```

---

### Update:

I found temporrary solution, thanks to [this](http://www.techytalk.info/start-script-on-network-manager-successful-connection/)

I created `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/74-sam-ipv6.sh` file, with following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

IF=$1
STATUS=$2

if [ "$IF" == "eth0" ]
then
    case "$2" in
        up)
        logger -s "74-sam-ipv6.sh eth0 up"
        ip -6 addr add 2001:470:**:**::*0/64 dev eth0
        ip -6 addr add 2001:470:**:**::*1/64 dev eth0
        ip -6 addr add 2001:470:**:**::*2/64 dev eth0
        ip -6 addr add 2001:470:**:**::*3/64 dev eth0
        ip -6 addr add 2001:470:**:**::*4/64 dev eth0

        curl "http://dyn.dns.he.net/nic/update?hostname=a.***my-domain***.ru&password=***&myip=2001:470:**:***::*0" > /dev/null
        curl "http://dyn.dns.he.net/nic/update?hostname=b.***my-domain***.ru&password=***&myip=2001:470:**:***::*1" > /dev/null
        curl "http://dyn.dns.he.net/nic/update?hostname=c.***my-domain***.ru&password=***&myip=2001:470:**:***::*3" > /dev/null
        curl "http://dyn.dns.he.net/nic/update?hostname=d.***my-domain***.ru&password=***&myip=2001:470:**:***::*2" > /dev/null
        curl "http://dyn.dns.he.net/nic/update?hostname=e.***my-domain***.ru&password=***&myip=2001:470:**:***::*4" > /dev/null
        echo ok

        ;;
        down)
        logger -s "74-sam-ipv6.sh eth0 down"
        ip -6 addr del 2001:470:**:***::*0/64 dev eth0
        ip -6 addr del 2001:470:**:***::*1/64 dev eth0
        ip -6 addr del 2001:470:**:***::*2/64 dev eth0
        ip -6 addr del 2001:470:**:***::*3/64 dev eth0
        ip -6 addr del 2001:470:**:***::*4/64 dev eth0
        echo ok

        ;;
        pre-up)
        logger -s "74-sam-ipv6.sh"
        ;;
        post-down)
        logger -s "74-sam-ipv6.sh"
        ;;
        *)
        logger -s "74-sam-ipv6.sh ------unknown-commmand-------------------------------------> $2"
        ;;
    esac
fi
```

Comment: My solution worked until I updated to xubuntu 15.04. (it uses systemd). Now when my server bootup nginx can not start, because it starts befor ipv6 addresses registered.

Comment: nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "jboss.***.***.**" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:81
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1

Answer (score 0):

I would set up my adresses in `/etc/network/interfaces` as an `auto` IPv6 device and then just add some `up` and `down` settings.  THat is because they are kind of static and the machine isn't likely to change IPv6 addresses.

I would add this to `/e/n/interfaces`:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet6 auto
    up ip -6 addr add 2001:470:**:**::*0/64 dev eth0
    up ip -6 addr add 2001:470:**:**::*1/64 dev eth0
    up ip -6 addr add 2001:470:**:**::*2/64 dev eth0
    up ip -6 addr add 2001:470:**:**::*3/64 dev eth0
    up ip -6 addr add 2001:470:**:**::*4/64 dev eth0
    post-up curl "http://dyn.dns.he.net/nic/update?hostname=a.***my-domain***.ru&password=***&myip=2001:470:**:***::*0" || true
    post-up curl "http://dyn.dns.he.net/nic/update?hostname=b.***my-domain***.ru&password=***&myip=2001:470:**:***::*1" || true
    post-up curl "http://dyn.dns.he.net/nic/update?hostname=c.***my-domain***.ru&password=***&myip=2001:470:**:***::*3" || true
    post-up curl "http://dyn.dns.he.net/nic/update?hostname=d.***my-domain***.ru&password=***&myip=2001:470:**:***::*2" || true
    post-up curl "http://dyn.dns.he.net/nic/update?hostname=e.***my-domain***.ru&password=***&myip=2001:470:**:***::*4" || true
    down ip -6 addr del 2001:470:**:**::*4/64 dev eth0
    down ip -6 addr del 2001:470:**:**::*3/64 dev eth0
    down ip -6 addr del 2001:470:**:**::*2/64 dev eth0
    down ip -6 addr del 2001:470:**:**::*1/64 dev eth0
    down ip -6 addr del 2001:470:**:**::*0/64 dev eth0
# eof
```

See manual page for `man 5 interfaces` for more information.

I would also replace the IPv4 address `127.0.1.1` to my real IPv4 address on `eth0`.  And I would copy that line and replace `127.0.1.1` address with my static IPv6 address.  I might also add names for the other IPv6 addresses, which would be useful in configuration files.